# Whatsapp Business Cloud API returning empty string when trying to download media

Tags: php, api, curl, whatsapp

I'm using the following lines of code (PHP) after successfuly retriving the media URL and then storing it in the $mediaURL variable for the file request, but it's returning an empty string. Already tried with postman and it returns a 500 internal server error...

** Edited **

```
self::writeLog('Media URL: '.$mediaURL);
self::writeLog('Preparing to download media - id: '.$media_id);

$curl = curl_init($mediaURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".self::$auth_token,
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

if (($resp = curl_exec($curl)) === false) {
    self::writeLog('cURL Error: '.curl_error($curl));
} else if ($resp == '') {
    self::writeLog('Empty string.');
    self::writeLog('URL: '.$mediaURL);
    self::writeLog('Headers: '.$headers[0]);
} else {
    self::writeLog($resp);
}
```

- writeLog is just a method that I use to write these messages on a txt file.

Comment: There's no option `CURL_URL`, it's `CURLOPT_URL`. You don't need to specify both that and the parameter to curl_init(), they're the same. Don't disable SSL checks, for the love of all that is holy. You're also never calling curl_exec().

Comment: check your php error logs. as @AlexHowansky pointed out, there's errors in this code trivially identifiable by just checking the error logs.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I uptaded the question with more details and the CURLOPT_URL correction...

Comment: Use curl_getinfo() and/or CURLOPT_VERBOSE to debug the connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i faced this issue before and the reason was not passing `User-Agent` to the API
lead to wrong values returns

I used the following method to download whatsapp-cloud media & it works fine with me

```
public function grabImage(string $url,string  $saveto) : bool {
    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST , "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");

    $headers    = [];
    $headers[]  = "Authorization: Bearer " . self::$adminToken;
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5";
    $headers[]  = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $raw = curl_exec($ch);
    
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    if((int)$httpcode == 200){
        // here save the $row content of file 
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The user agent alone did the trick :)

Comment: most welcome! I have some little experience with WhatsApp-cloud & WhatsApp on-premises integrations, so please feel free to contact me anytime you face any issue with it