# Error WhatAspp cloud API save image using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, whatsapp

I am having a problem downloading images of a message sent by the user in WhatsApp cloud API, when performing a test in Postman, if I get the image.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 
'https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/? 
mid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ext=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&hash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

[image]

but on my server when executing the cURL code in php it redirects me to:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to download the image by applying this example of Omar Tamman:

[Whatsapp Business Cloud API returning empty string when trying to download media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491018/whatsapp-business-cloud-api-returning-empty-string-when-trying-to-download-media)

My example that worked:

```
$ch = curl_init($rptaUrlMedia);

$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$output_filename = 'demo.png';
$fp = fopen($output_filename, 'wb');
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST , "GET");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE , $fp);

$headers = [];
$headers[]  = "Authorization: Bearer " . $token;
$headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5";
$headers[]  = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
    
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

demo.png is an image file already created where you save the result

What I am seeing now is to be able to identify what type of file is image, video, audio.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, then I added the user-agent and I went ahead, however, I still can't download the image getting as a response "something went wrong"

Add this line to the curl options:

```
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'),
```

Comment: Hi,  add the USERAGENT and I get the following error message "There was a problem with this request. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can."

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is 100% working.

use shell_exec function to execute curl instead of curl_setopt

```
public static function download_image($url){

    $token = "xxx";

    shell_exec("cd upload && curl  \
             '".$url."' \
       -H 'Authorization: Bearer ".$token."' > ".uniqid().".png");

 }
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and looking in other forums [WhatsApp Cloud API Receiving Images from Users Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214351/whatsapp-cloud-api-receiving-images-from-users-error)

I found that in the header the User-Agent is very important!
"Content-Type: image/jpeg", "Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","User-Agent: curl/7.64.1"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34838015)