# Unable to save response as image in WhatsApp cloud API using curl and PHP

Tags: php, curl, postman, whatsapp

I am facing saving image from curl image.
right now used in curl cli and Postman worked in both but in case of PHP does not work.

Working on curl and Postman:

curl e.g.

```
curl  \
 'https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=874575937325370&ext=1672595325&hash=ATtpPT6xh31fKJgKmv5gALTnHvlLR8GOZEKR5Ly4WHo-UA' \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' > image.jpg
```

Current PHP code:

```
$rptaUrlMedia = "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=874575937325370&ext=1672591353&hash=ATu_gBkH9rfUoUwp6-js54WQj3ycCcUHm5Mys4W5slUQxQ";

$ch = curl_init($rptaUrlMedia);

$token = "xxx";

$output_filename = 'demo.png';
$fp = fopen($output_filename, 'wb');
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST , "GET");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE , $fp);

$headers = [];
$headers[]  = "Authorization: Bearer " . $token;
$headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5";
$headers[]  = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
    
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Please let me know what I am missing in curl cli and PHP script so, I can save my response in jpg format.

My main purpose to get image from URL and download it as similar Postman did while saving as response.

I have go to another Stack Overflow answers but does not find solutions.

[Error WhatAspp cloud API save image using cURL and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229142/error-whataspp-cloud-api-save-image-using-curl-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

-In My case I had to use Guzzlehttp library :

```
function downloadMedia($mediaUrl , $extension)
{
    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $response = $client->get($mediaUrl, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->accessToken}"
            ]
        ]);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $filename = uniqid('till_slip_') . '_' . time() . '.'.$extension; // Modify the filename
            $filePath = '../till_slips/' . $filename;
            file_put_contents($filePath, $response->getBody());
            $fname =  'uploads/till_slips/' . $filename;
            return $fname;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```